# Programmatically removing a module from imports in an Angular module

Tags: angular, parsing, module

I'm currently working on coding my own boilerplate with all the necessary functionality, that I think I might need in the future. For that, I thought of creating an "initialization" script that removes certain features from the project.

I think deleting the files is not that hard, but I would also like to parse e.g. `app.module.ts` , to remove the "import" lines, as well as the module from imports array.

Is there some kind of a parser, to parse and re-write Angular modules or would I have to write my own parser and do everything manually?